# Running a .NET Program as a Background Service

Tags: .net, asp.net, backgroundworker

Here is the simple scenario that I want to apply;

1. There is a .NET application(console or windows) appA and this code updates a large global variable(+50MB) in the project every 30sec.
2. I have another application appB which is a .NET web application and I want to be able to access the updated value of global variable in appA from appB whenever I want.

What do you suggest to me for this purpose?

Comment: Are these two always going to run on the same computer?

Comment: Your going to need to identify some technology (db, webservice, file, etc) to serve as your integration layer.  Then your question can get answered simply.

Comment: @James Yes they will run on the same computer. @BozoJoe I can use any of those technology but writing to db or to a file seems a bad way since my variable will be very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flat file, database, remoting, or sockets are some ways you can do it.  The answer would vary based on certain factors, such as whether or not the data is sensitve, how many computers you plan on distributing the app to, and whether or not multiple instances of appA could exist.

Comment: Hello DaMartyr, the variable will be large(50MB+) and writing it to a file or a database does not seem so feasible. This variable will change every 30sec, is it still a good idea to store it in db or file?

Answer (score 2):

My initial thoughts are to have application A run as a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and have that write to some shared location for the web application.

Comment: I see Jason, I also thought something like this but the variable will be large(let's say 50MB+), is it still feasible to store it on a file and loading it up from web application? Can't I create something like a windows service which is running all the time and a web service for that specific windows service which will access the variable and return it back from a simple REST call from web application?

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 are running on the same machine, you can use the Registry or Store it on a file or database.

If it may run on different machine database might be the best alternative.